# Can we darken the followed links on superuser just a smidgen?

Tags: feature-request, design

The links on large text (either followed or unfollowed) look fine, but the small link text for a followed link is a bit bright for a white background.

I don't have a suggestion for a replacement color (could a followed link be text-decorated in some other way?) but light-light-blue small text on a white background is difficult to read.

Answer (score 1):

I know that RGB isn't the best color space to make this argument, but it should still be obvious that the proposal just doesn't work. Anything darker (enough to be more readable) is barely distinguishable from the regular link color.

[image: 5 color samples, current regular and visited link color, as well as a few colors between them]

Please provide actual colors, ideally mockups, for your proposal, that make visited links more readable *and* keep regular and visited links distinguishable.

The same in Arial 14pt, like on Super User:

[image: same image, much smaller]

Comment: Colors might be minimally off since I didn't even launch a graphics editor here, and color correction can lead to weird behavior.